# Remember multiple active tabs upon page refresh in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the best way to remember the active tabs on a page that has more than one groups of tabs (tabs in tabs).

I am trying to build a layout for a more complex application that has embedded tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the active tabs info in a localStorage variable and when you refresh and reload the page you can access the same and rerender the html according to it.

More info on localStorage:

[W3School Explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[A nice blog on it](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/)